# On upload the image of same name does not display error in php

Tags: php

help me get the error on same name image

```
<form action="img.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" value=""/>
   <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

my action page is.

```
<?php    
    $image_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $first_char = substr($image_name, 0, 1);

    if (!file_exists($first_char)) {
        mkdir($first_char);
    }

    $file = ($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $uploadfile = $first_char;
    if(file_exists($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile."/".$file);
        echo "GOOD";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
?>
```

as I submit any image it display `GOOD` message.
on the other hand It work well

Comment: You just do the wrong check: `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` instead of `$uploadfile."/".$file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the temporary directory where the image is moved from. But I think you would want to check the destination if theres already a file with the same name.

Try changing `if(file_exists($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))` to `if(file_exists($uploadfile."/".$file))`

Answer (score 0):

your code is doing the wrong check,

```
if(file_exists($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
```

your checking to see if the just uploaded file exists, instead you will have to do the following.

```
if(!file_exists($uploadfile."/".$file))
```

which will check if a file exist with the same name, if it doesn't then you can move the new file in, if it does then you can display ERROR.